# IsProviderEnabled always return true either Location service is enabled or disabled

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, locationmanager, location-provider

I am working in xamarin forms. I need to check the location service is enabled or not for android. I wrote the following code :

```
   LocationManager locMgr = GetSystemService(LocationService) as LocationManager;
   string Provider = LocationManager.GpsProvider;
   var islocationEnabled = locMgr.IsProviderEnabled(Provider);
```

But I am always getting true value either location service is enabled or not. How I can get the correct value?

Comment: Do you use emulator or real device?

Comment: I tested in both emulator and real device. But getting same result true

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Plugin.Geolocator.CrossGeolocator, be aware of this:

*IsGeolocationEnabled* and *IsGeolocationAvailable* returns the correct info only AFTER the App Permissions for Locations was allowed!!!!!

If you want to know if the locations services are enabled on the mobile BEFORE you allow the Location App Permission, you have to do like this:

Android

```
  public bool IsLocationGpsEnabled()
    {
        var _locationManager = (LocationManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);
        if (_locationManager.IsProviderEnabled("gps"))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

iOS

```
 public bool IsLocationGpsEnabled()
    {
        return CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are working in Xamarin.Forms, why not use the nuget package [Xam.Plugin.Geolocator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Geolocator/)? I'm using it and I put my location code in my PCL so it's cross-platform and not repeated. You could take this snippet and put it straight in your android project if you really only needed location in Android.

(I usually wrap plugins so I can minimize their impact, hence the wrapper class and the interface in the example)

```cs
public class LocationService : ILocationService
{
    readonly ILogger _logger;
    public LocationService(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<IPosition> GetPosition()
    {
        var locator = Plugin.Geolocator.CrossGeolocator.Current;

        //1609 meters in a mile. Half a mile accuracy should be good 
        //since we are rounding to whole numbers
        locator.DesiredAccuracy = 800;

        try
        {
            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(5000);

            return position.ToPosition();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Log(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This could all be condensed to one line if needed:

```
return await Plugin.Geolocator.CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync();
```

EDIT:
The plugin also has methods for determining the status of geolocation like [`IsGeolocationEnabled`](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin/blob/master/src/Geolocator.Plugin.Abstractions/IGeolocator.cs#L45) and [`IsGeolocationAvailable`](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin/blob/master/src/Geolocator.Plugin.Abstractions/IGeolocator.cs#L40).
Since it is open-source, you can view the [implementation on Android](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin/blob/master/src/Geolocator.Plugin.Android/GeolocatorImplementation.cs).

Comment: But I need to know the location service is enabled or not. Here you are getting the location of device not about the location service is enabled or not.

Comment: @anand it is an open-source project so you can see the implementation. It has the methods that you're looking for if you just go check it out. I updated the post with exact links.

Comment: Thanks for update, I tried with it but still I am getting true in both cases either location service is enabled or not.